# Relationship between TCP and IP Packets

Tags: ip, tcp, router

So I have trouble finding a source that describes whether the TCP Packet is the payload of the IP Datagram or vice versa.  I imagine the TCP Packet must be the payload because presumably the router can divide the IP Datagram therefore splitting up the TCP Packet and then the final router would have to reassamble them.  Am I right?

Comment: That's my understanding. I'm not convinced that you're on-topic, though.

Comment: TCP *over* IP. Pretty much says it all. IP routers know how to deal with UDP *over* IP as well. What does Wikipedia have to say?

Answer (score 4):

If by "payload" you're referring to the data that comes after an IP header, then TCP is the "payload" of an IP packet when receiving data, since it's an upper level protocol.

The proper term for networking is actually [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(networking)) though.

It basically works by adding on progressive layers of protocols as information travels down from the application to the wire. After transmission, the packets are re-assembled and then the packets are error checked, the headers are stripped off, and what you are referring to as the "payload" becomes the next chunk of information that is checked. Once all of the outer protocol layers are stripped off the server/client has the information that directly corresponds to what the application sent.

Answer (score -1):

Tcp\IP are two important proctocols. Tcp is connection oriented, while IP is a connection-less protocol. IP stands for a logical address, which works as packet address. The source packet has destination address for its destination. Tcp works with this logical address and helps the packets to reach their destinations, and provides acknowledgement when packet reached to its destination.